# Dynamic ngFor leaves behind old values

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement some system of favorites in Angular 5, but every time I add or remove a favorite from the list, the displayed list keeps the old list as well. That is, if I start with the list of favorites [a,b,c] and add a new one d, I end up with the list [a,b,c,d,a,b,c]. For instance, here it is with just a single favorite :

[image]

And here it is after I attempt to add a new one :

[image]

The effect compounds : if I add n new favorites, I get n copies of the list. This is purely a dynamical effect as if I just refresh the page, the list displays normally as it should. The problem also doesn't seem to come from the favorites array as it never seems to have duplicated entries

The basic code involved is the sidebar used in Clever, modified for the purpose of a favorite list. The components involved are AppSidebarNavComponent :

```
export class AppSidebarNavComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit
{

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    if(this.projectService.fav === null)
    {
      let usersub = this.userService.userObs.subscribe(user =>
      {
        let favs = [];

        this.projectService.loadFavorites(user.id);
        let favsub = this.projectService.favorites.subscribe(data =>
          {
            let favs = [];
            for(let fav of data)
            {
              let name = fav.Program;
              let url = '/geometry/' + fav.projectid;
              let child = {name: name, url: url, icon: 'icon-star', fav: true};
              favs.push(child);
            }
            if(this.navigation[1].hasOwnProperty("children"))
            {
              this.navigation[1]["children"] = favs;
            }
          });
      });
    }
  }


}
```

The component AppSidebarNavItemComponent :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar-nav-item',
  template: `
    <li>
      <app-sidebar-nav-link [link]='item'></app-sidebar-nav-link>
    </li>
    <ng-template #dropdown>
      <li>
        <app-sidebar-nav-dropdown [link]='item'></app-sidebar-nav-dropdown>
      </li>
    </ng-template>
    `
})
```

The component AppSidebarNavLinkComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar-nav-link',
  template: `
    <ng-container>
      <div>
        <a [routerLink]="[link]">
          {{ link.name }}
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="deletefav(link)">
          <i class="icon-close center-full"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppSidebarNavLinkComponent {

  public deletefav(link)
  {
    this.projectService.removeFavorite(this.userService.user.id, link.name).subscribe(data =>
    {
      this.projectService.loadFavorites(this.userService.user.id, true);
    });
  }
}
```

and AppSidebarNavDropdownComponent

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <a>
      {{ link.name }}
    </a>
    <ul>
      <app-sidebar-nav-item *ngFor="let child of link.children" 
      [item]='child'></app-sidebar-nav-item>
    </ul>
  `
})
```

I've tried to complete the subscription after it was done loading the favorites, but this just makes the list never updates anymore. I've tried to manually delete the entries in the list, but then Angular doesn't seem to like it and it just crashes when it tries to insert the favorites. No other *ngFor related component seems to display this behaviour and I'm not sure what is causing this.

Comment: Please provide minimal code to reproduce/identify your issue, and not your whole code, as it is very tedious to read.

Comment: There we go, it should be a bit more readable and hopefully still able to identify the problem.

Comment: Well I see a remove fav function, but I don't see an add fav function, is that normal ?

Comment: Stackblitz plz - TDLR;

Comment: The add favorite function is part of a service which another component uses. Should I add it?

Comment: Please add it, but https://stackblitz.com is better.

Comment: The component is part of the whole Clever site template, so excising everything that's not related to that part is a bit challenging. I'll try to replicate it on stackblitz to the best of my abilities.

Answer (score 1):

Hello visitor from the future. If you too have a problem with that issue, the solution seems to be that apparently, using dynamical components rather than HTML code directly seems to be the issue. Replacing

```
  <app-sidebar-nav-item *ngFor="let child of link.children" 
  [item]='child'></app-sidebar-nav-item>
```

with

```
  <ng-component *ngFor="let child of link.children">
      <div>
         ...
      </div>
  </ng-component>
```

where the div contains the appropriate content of app-sidebar-nav-item seemed to do the trick.

Comment: i just discovered the same problem and solution after a bit of trial and error.
 then i found your answer. I'm Using angular 5 as well. Since the children template `app-sidebar-nav-item` is used elsewhere, embedding the template directly is not an option. Maybe a bug specific to angular 5? upgrading to angular 6 it's also impossible at the moment for us. Have you found a different solution that fix the deletion of children components ?

Answer (score 1):

I contribute to this thread because I've just run into a similar problem, so I guess someone can benefit from this, at least if working with Clarity Design System.

I'm using the [Clarity Datagrid component](https://v2.clarity.design/datagrid) to display search results. Although the results array was updated correctly after each search, the results kept accumulating in the view, either using *ngFor or Clarity custom directive *clrDgItems.

I don't know which was the source of the problem, but managed to solve it updating the project's dependencies; in particular:

```
Name                   Version                  Command to update
--------------------------------------------------------------------
@angular/cli           9.0.3 -> 9.0.4           ng update @angular/cli
@angular/core          9.0.2 -> 9.0.4           ng update @angular/core
@clr/angular           2.3.8 -> 3.0.0           ng update @clr/angular
```